# Can compass/coffee do this? Another approach?

Tags: javascript, css, compass-sass

What I want to do is use css3 for buttons *if* the browser supports gradients and rounded corners, and if not, use set graphics.

I have compass and coffee at my disposal.

Comment: @steveax I don't randomly stab at things and hope something will bleed ;) I ask the experts..or google.

Comment: Zenph: the culture of StackOverflow sways towards helping people who have shown some attempt at solving the problem rather than asking "gimme da codes".

Comment: @Diodeus and why would I want someone to 'gimme da codes'? Are they going to maintain those codes for me, too? Maybe they will teach me what those codes do? Please, I'm far from lazy. Whether I've shown an attempt at solving or not doesn't matter; I have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that's impossible with pure css, and compass simply translates the code to pure css. If you would like to do this, you'd have to use some type of Javascript to load different stylesheets depending on browser.

Answer (score 0):

CSS alone cannot do what you want.

[Moderizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a JavaScript utility that can help you detect which features are supported in the browser and allow you to run scripts accordingly.